# SSRS 2012 reporting services security issue

Tags: reporting-services, reporting-services-2012

I'm attempting to set some security and mailing settings on my SSRS server, however I'm getting the following error:

> SQL Server Reporting Services
>
> Error
>
> An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due
>   to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the
>   database. (rsReportServerDatabaseError) Get Online Help Procedure or
>   function 'SetPolicy' expects parameter '@PrimarySecDesc', which was
>   not supplied.
>
> Home

Not sure what's going on as SETPOLICY appears to be in my DB as a storedproc....

I believe it to be a problem with the .config files, which were modified in order to get the reports working with anonymous log in, however when that was done, the report manager no longer worked. Is there any way to reset all .config files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was errors in the .config files - reinstalling SSRS 2012 fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

SETPOLICY is related to security. Try to check the  tag on your rsreportserver.config file.

Mine looks like this:

```
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsNegotiate/>
        <RSWindowsNTLM/>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
    <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

Comment: Hmm, that just gives ERROR now when trying to load report manager.
I did change the config files of the reporting service itself so that authentication was no longer required - would this be the issue?

Comment: probably. what error are you getting now? did you restart the ssrs service completely?

Comment: I did. Getting this error:
 
Error
 
The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.

Comment: can you connect to SSRS using SSMS?

Comment: Yeah seems to be connecting fine.

Comment: so its something wrong with your report manager. does report server connect?

Comment: Yeah connects fine and the reports themselves display fine.

Comment: is there anyway I can restore all the .config files to their original state?